# C puzzle: shuffled code for inverted triangle pattern output

Tags: c

The following program is *shuffled*:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n,x=1,y,z,a,b=2,i,j,k;
  scanf("%d",&n);
  y=n+1;
  z=n-1;
  a=n-1;
  for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
  {
    x=1;
    for(j=1;j<y;j++)
    {
      printf("%d ",x);
      if(i%2!=0)
      {
        z=z-1;
      }
      a=a-2;
      z=(n-1)-b;
      b=b+2;
      printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
      for(k=1;k<=a;k++)
      {
        printf("%d ",z);
        y=y-2;
        printf("\n");
      }
    }
    x++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Once sorted all the lines in the correct order (ignore the current indentation) it should compile and, given an input of **5**, it should output this pattern

```
12345
4321
123
21
1
```

I tried several times, but to no avail. How could I find a solution?

Comment: Please clikc [edit], paste your indented code in place of the one you enclosed in ticks, select code that you pasted, and click `[{ }]` button at the top of the editor. This will produce code that looks readable on a page.

Comment: thank you for your help this is 1st time using it@dasblinkenlight

Comment: I'm not sure SO is a place for such puzzles. Anyway - there is no way you can produce the output `12345 4321 123 21 1` using exactly those lines. You probably posted the code incorrectly.

Comment: I'll rollback the "formatting fix", since inserting indentation obscures the fact that the program is _shuffled_.

Comment: @Bob__ - Regarding your edit: I don't think that re-inserting the indentation does the question any good, but since you mentioned to _ignore the current indentation_, it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

A possible way for finding the correct order of this program is to realize that

- there's an outer loop which runs through the *n = 5* individual output lines (`1 2 3 4 5` to `1`); this is the loop `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)`
- then there has to be a distinction of cases for increasing (`1 2 3 4 5`) and decreasing (`4 3 2 1`) order of output; this is the `if(i%2!=0)`
- there are two more loops given, of which one has to be for increasing numbers and belongs into the `if` block, while the other has to be for decreasing numbers and belongs into the `else` block
- after initial setting, some variables (`x`, `y`) are used only in the increasing case, and others (`z`, `a`, `b`) only in the decreasing case, thus referring statements belong to the corresponding `if`/`else` block.

Below is the functioning program, side by side with the original unsorted lines:

```
#include<stdio.h>                //               #include<stdio.h>
                                 //
int main()                       //               int main()
{                                //               {
    int n,x=1,y,z,a,b=2,i,j,k;   //                 int n,x=1,y,z,a,b=2,i,j,k;
    scanf("%d",&n);              //      (1)        scanf("%d",&n);
    y=n+1;                       //                 y=n+1;            
    z=n-1;                       //                 z=n-1;
    a=n-1;                       //                 a=n-1;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)            //                 for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
    {                            //  ____________   {
        if(i%2!=0)               //                   x=1; 
        {                        //      (3)          for(j=1;j<y;j++)
            x=1;                 //                   {
            for(j=1;j<y;j++)     //  ____________       printf("%d ",x);
            {                    //      (2)            if(i%2!=0)
                printf("%d ",x); //  ____________       {
                x++;             //                       z=z-1;          
            }                    //                     } 
            y=y-2;               //                     a=a-2;
            printf("\n");        //      (7)            z=(n-1)-b;
        }                        //                     b=b+2;
        else                     //                     printf("\n"); 
        {                        //  _____________    }
            for(k=1;k<=a;k++)    //                   else
            {                    //                   {
                printf("%d ",z); //      (6)            for(k=1;k<=a;k++)   
                z=z-1;           //                     {
            }                    // ______________        printf("%d ",z);
            a=a-2;               //                       y=y-2;
            z=(n-1)-b;           //      (5)              printf("\n");
            b=b+2;               // ______________      }
            printf("\n");        // ______________    }
        }                        //      (4)          x++;    
    }                            // ______________  }
    return 0;                    //      (8)        return 0;
}                                //               }
```

Comment: I believe that a copy-pastable and testable snippet is better, but feel free to rollback the edit, of course.

Comment: @Bob__ - Maybe … anyway, one can see the previous version in the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems a little too complicated. How about this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int n, x = 1, i, j;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  for (i = n; i; i--)
  {
    if (x > 0)  for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) printf("%d ", j);
    else        for (j = i; 1 <= j; j--) printf("%d ", j);
    printf("\n");
    x *= -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please note the first line in the question: "*program* is shuffled as below...help me with the correct order"... While this code gives the correct output, I'm afraid it doesn't really answer the (old and probably off-topic) question.

Comment: @Bob__ - The not quite polished language of the question does not suggest to me that it is to be taken that literally. The age of the question is irrelevant.

Comment: @Bob__ - After taking a second look, I think you are right.